# Aproximação da função cosseno usando os n primeiros termos de uma série

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dados x real e n natural, calcular uma aproximação para cos x através dos
n primeiros termos da seguinte série:

```
cos x = 1/1 - (x**2)/2! + (x**4)/4! - (x**6)/6! + ... + ((-1)**k)*(x**2k)/((2k)!)
```

Minha tentativa de solução:

```
import math

#x =1 #calcular o cosx
#k =1 #número de termos da série

k = int(input("Digite k: "))
x = float(input("Digite x: "))
soma =0.0
for i in range(0,k+1):
    soma += ((-1)**k)*(x**(2*k))/(math.factorial(2*k))

print(soma)
```

Qual o erro da implementação? Como corrigir?

Answer (score 2):

O seu primeiro problema é que quando `x = 0`, `soma = 1`. Logo, deveria inicializar soma com o valor 1 e não 0.
De seguida, está a utilizar *i* para iterar de 0 até *k* no entanto, dentro do loop colocou *k* em vez de *i*. 
Seguindo estas correções, sugiro que o código correto seja:

```
import math

#x =1 #calcular o cosx
#k =1 #número de termos da série

k = int(input("Digite k: "))
x = float(input("Digite x: "))
soma = 0.0

for i in range(0,k):
    soma = soma + ((-1) ** i) * (x ** (2 * i)) / (math.factorial(2 * i))

print(soma)
```

Comment: obrigado. Estou tentando resolver vários problemas para pegar o jeito em programação!

Comment: acho que ainda tem algo de errado no código. Por exemplo, cos1 =0.54 mas o programa calcula como -1.6534391534391533e-06 com k=5

Comment: quando k=0, a soma já dá 1 no loop for. se fizer soma =1, ficará 1+1

Comment: soma = 0.0 mesmo!

Comment: Continuo a achar que `soma = 1` pois cos(0) = 1.

Comment: Quando utiliza `k = 0` está a fazer uma aproximação ao cosseno com 0 iterações, logo não pode esperar um resultado próximo do real

Comment: No entanto, não sou matemático nem nada do género, logo, tome esta resposta com atenção

Comment: Eu só comentei para você editar o valor de soma e eu aceitar a resposta!